# Changing Column Width for betterposter template

Tags: overleaf, column-width

I'm trying to change the middle column width on the betterposter template, so that the left and right columns are wider and that the middle section is a bit more narrow. I'm using the standard A0 template.

I have tried to modify the left and right columns through

```
The left column, \setlength{\leftbarwidth}{value}.
The right column, \setlength{\rightbarwidth}{value}.
```

But nothing changes. Do I have to change the paper width too? I have the standard settings:

```
\newlength{\leftbarwidth}
\newlength{\rightbarwidth}
\newlength{\columnmarginvertical}
\newlength{\columnmarginhorizontal}
\newlength{\maincolumnmarginvertical}
\newlength{\maincolumnmarginhorizontal}

%%%% SIZING OPTIONS

\newcommand{\fontsizestandard}{\fontsize{32.00}{50.50} \selectfont}
\newcommand{\fontsizemain}{\fontsize{116.00}{220.00} \selectfont}
\newcommand{\fontsizetitle}{\fontsize{80.00}{120.00} \selectfont}
\newcommand{\fontsizeauthor}{\fontsize{48.00}{68.00} \selectfont}
\newcommand{\fontsizesection}{\fontsize{48.00}{68.00} \selectfont}

\DeclareOption{a2paper}{
\geometry{a2paper}
\renewcommand{\fontsizestandard}{\fontsize{16.00}{25.00} \selectfont}
\renewcommand{\fontsizemain}{\fontsize{58.00}{110.00} \selectfont}
\renewcommand{\fontsizetitle}{\fontsize{40.00}{50.00} \selectfont}
\renewcommand{\fontsizeauthor}{\fontsize{24.00}{34.00} \selectfont}
\renewcommand{\fontsizesection}{\fontsize{24.00}{34.00} \selectfont}
}

\DeclareOption{a1paper}{
\geometry{a1paper}
\renewcommand{\fontsizestandard}{\fontsize{22.63}{35.36} \selectfont}
\renewcommand{\fontsizemain}{\fontsize{82.02}{155.56} \selectfont}
\renewcommand{\fontsizetitle}{\fontsize{56.57}{70.71} \selectfont}
\renewcommand{\fontsizeauthor}{\fontsize{33.94}{48.08} \selectfont}
\renewcommand{\fontsizesection}{\fontsize{33.94}{48.08} \selectfont}
}


\DeclareOption{a0paper}{
\geometry{a0paper}
}

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ProcessOptions\relax

%% Default values for lengths
\setlength{\leftbarwidth}{0.2\paperwidth}
\setlength{\rightbarwidth}{0.2\paperwidth}
\setlength{\columnmarginvertical}{0.025\paperheight}
\setlength{\columnmarginhorizontal}{0.025\paperheight}
\setlength{\maincolumnmarginvertical}{0.07\paperheight}
\setlength{\maincolumnmarginhorizontal}{0.07\paperheight}
```

I wanted the white left and white columns to be larger, and the green area to be more narrow

[image: intention]

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that). As it is, you aren't showing neither code that we can test, nor a screenshot to show what the problem is.

Comment: Merged your reply with your question and recommended your reply for deleteion.

Answer (score -1):

If you remove all of the `\newlength` and `fontsize` commands, it works perfectly.
This is my minimal example:

```
\documentclass{betterposter}
\geometry{paperheight=1209mm,paperwidth=861mm,hmargin=10mm,vmargin=10mm}

%\newlength{\leftbarwidth}
%\newlength{\rightbarwidth}
%\newlength{\columnmarginvertical}
%\newlength{\columnmarginhorizontal}
%\newlength{\maincolumnmarginvertical}
%\newlength{\maincolumnmarginhorizontal}

%%%% SIZING OPTIONS

%\newcommand{\fontsizestandard}{\fontsize{32.00}{50.50} \selectfont}
%\newcommand{\fontsizemain}{\fontsize{116.00}{220.00} \selectfont}
%\newcommand{\fontsizetitle}{\fontsize{80.00}{120.00} \selectfont}
%\newcommand{\fontsizeauthor}{\fontsize{48.00}{68.00} \selectfont}
%\newcommand{\fontsizesection}{\fontsize{48.00}{68.00} \selectfont}

\DeclareOption{a2paper}{
\geometry{a2paper}
\renewcommand{\fontsizestandard}{\fontsize{16.00}{25.00} \selectfont}
\renewcommand{\fontsizemain}{\fontsize{58.00}{110.00} \selectfont}
\renewcommand{\fontsizetitle}{\fontsize{40.00}{50.00} \selectfont}
\renewcommand{\fontsizeauthor}{\fontsize{24.00}{34.00} \selectfont}
\renewcommand{\fontsizesection}{\fontsize{24.00}{34.00} \selectfont}
}

\DeclareOption{a1paper}{
\geometry{a1paper}
\renewcommand{\fontsizestandard}{\fontsize{22.63}{35.36} \selectfont}
\renewcommand{\fontsizemain}{\fontsize{82.02}{155.56} \selectfont}
\renewcommand{\fontsizetitle}{\fontsize{56.57}{70.71} \selectfont}
\renewcommand{\fontsizeauthor}{\fontsize{33.94}{48.08} \selectfont}
\renewcommand{\fontsizesection}{\fontsize{33.94}{48.08} \selectfont}
}


\DeclareOption{a0paper}{
\geometry{a0paper}
}

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ProcessOptions\relax

%% Default values for lengths
\setlength{\leftbarwidth}{0.2\paperwidth}
\setlength{\rightbarwidth}{0.2\paperwidth}
\setlength{\columnmarginvertical}{0.025\paperheight}
\setlength{\columnmarginhorizontal}{0.025\paperheight}
\setlength{\maincolumnmarginvertical}{0.07\paperheight}
\setlength{\maincolumnmarginhorizontal}{0.07\paperheight}

\begin{document}    
    
\betterposter{
    \maincolumn{
        main column
}
}{%left column

on the left

}{right column
on the right

}
\end{document}
```

When I change the values of `\setlength{leftbarwidth}` here, it works for me.